# Lead/lag in R but only for rows that meet a yes/no condition

Tags: r, function, lag

I have a dataset of patient visits that looks like this:

```
   visit infection treatment
1      1  negative         1
2      2  negative         1
3      3  positive         1
4      4  negative         0
5      5  positive         1
6      6  positive         0
7      7  positive         1
8      8  negative         0
9      9  negative         1
10    10  negative         1
11    11  negative         0
12    12  positive         1
13    13  positive         1
```

I want to create a column, `treatment_second_neg_visit`, that tells me if the patient had a treatment on the second infection-negative visit following the visit at hand (and `NA` if two negative-infection visits do not follow the visit at hand). Basically, lead/lag but only when a certain condition is met.

**NOTE:** Even for rows with positive infection, I am still interested in the second infection-*negative* visit that follows it.

**Example 1:** For the first visit (Row 1), the *next* negative visit is Row 2, and the *second* negative visit is Row 4, where treatment=0. So the value of `treatment_second_neg_visit` should be 0 for Row 1.

**Example 2:** For the second visit (Row 2), the *next* negative visit is Row 4, and the *second* negative visit is Row 8, where treatment=0. So the value of `treatment_second_neg_visit` should be 0 for Row 2.

The final output should be:

```
visit    infection  treatment treatment_second_neg_visit
    1     negative          1                          0
    2     negative          1                          0
    3     positive          1                          0
    4     negative          0                          1
    5     positive          1                          1
    6     positive          0                          1
    7     positive          1                          1
    8     negative          0                          1
    9     negative          1                          0
    10    negative          1                          NA
    11    negative          0                          NA
    12    positive          1                          NA
    13    positive          1                          NA
```

Code to create the dataset:

```
dat <- data.frame(visit = 1:13, infection = c("negative", "negative", "positive", "negative", "positive", "positive", "positive", "negative", "negative", "negative", "negative", "positive", "positive"), treatment = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1))
```

Base R or dplyr is ideal, but open to any correct solutions.

Comment: What about when `infection = 'positive'` ? How do you calculate `treatment_second_neg_visit` for it?

Comment: @RonakShah Infection at the current visit is irrelevant. You still just need to find the second negative visit following that visit. e.g. For Row 3, the first negative visit following it is Row 4, and second negative visit following it is Row 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** First create a column `neg` that gives the number of negatives so far and then perform a left self join on the indicated condition.

```
library(sqldf)

dat2 <- transform(dat, neg = cumsum(infection == 'negative'))

sqldf("select a.visit, a.infection, a.treatment, b.treatment second
  from dat2 a
  left join dat2 b on a.neg + 2 = b.neg and b.infection = 'negative' ")
```

giving:

```
   visit infection treatment second
1      1  negative         1      0
2      2  negative         1      0
3      3  positive         1      0
4      4  negative         0      1
5      5  positive         1      1
6      6  positive         0      1
7      7  positive         1      1
8      8  negative         0      1
9      9  negative         1      0
10    10  negative         1     NA
11    11  negative         0     NA
12    12  positive         1     NA
13    13  positive         1     NA
```

or we could do it all in one sql statement:

```
sqldf("with dat2 as (
  select *, sum(infection = 'negative') over (rows unbounded preceding) neg
  from dat
)
select a.visit, a.infection, a.treatment, b.treatment second
  from dat2 a
  left join dat2 b on a.neg + 2 = b.neg and b.infection = 'negative' ")
```

**2) dplyr**  `dat2` is `dat` with an additional column giving the number of negatives up to and including the current row.  We then perform the indicated left join.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(neg = cumsum(infection == 'negative'))
   
dat2 %>%
  mutate(neg = neg + 2) %>% 
  left_join(filter(dat2, infection == 'negative'), "neg", suffix = c("", ".y")) %>%
  select(visit, infection, treatment, second = treatment.y)
```

Comment: Could you explain what's going on in the sql code here?

Comment: For each row of instance a of dat2 it pulls in that row of instance b of dat2 that satisfies the condition shown on the last line of the sql statement.  It returns all a instance columns, a.*, and the treatment column from the joined row of instance b which it calls second.

Comment: This code happens to get the right answer here, but its incorrect because say Row 3 is a "positive" visit. Your code finds the treatment for the second positive visit following it, but I need the second negative visit following it (e.g. the Row 3 value for `second` should be based on the second negative visit following it, which is Row 8, not the second positive visit following it, which is Row 6).

Comment: Everything works out in the above case, but try it on this slightly adapted dataset: `dat <- data.frame(visit = 1:13, infection = c("negative", "negative", "positive", "negative", "positive", "positive", "positive", "negative", "negative", "negative", "negative", "positive", "positive"), treatment = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1))`.

Comment: On this new dataset, the Row 3 value for `second` should be 0, but your code gives it a 1.

Comment: The question didn't define what to do with positives but now that you have I have modified the code to do that.

Comment: It did - the statement "I want to create a column, `treatment_second_neg_visit`, that tells me if the patient had a treatment on the second infection-negative visit following the visit at hand" applies to all rows of the data frame, as the "visit at hand" isn't specified to be a negative visit. Anyhow, I have updated the question to make it more clear as it may not have been clear through my wording. Thank you for your answer to this question. It was clear and very helpful! I went with method #2.